# magento get Internal Server Error when click payment methods on backend's Configuration

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am a new guy for Magento. When I click on backend's System>Configuration>Sales>Payment Methods, I got Internal Server Error. I checked error log file, it shows the below error:

> [Tue Nov 29 20:25:39.934637 2016] [access_compat:error] [pid 306944:tid 140107193476864] [client 210.5.50.143:55854] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/vhosts/baoho.nz/httpdocs/app/etc/local.xml
>   [Tue Nov 29 20:25:40.318493 2016] [:error] [pid 306946:tid 140107373123328] [client 222.153.188.223] ModSecurity: Output filter: Response body too large (over limit of 524288, total not specified). [hostname "baoho.nz"] [uri "/index.php/admin/system_config/edit/section/payment/key/0ad75a974774456d274ebf7c4bcf4cb1/"] [unique_id "WD0tb@nx70z3ONKpFlNGtgAAAEI"]
>   [Tue Nov 29 20:25:40.318964 2016] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 306946:tid 140107373123328] [client 222.153.188.223:55836] AH01068: Got bogus version 101, referer: http://baoho.nz/index.php/admin/system_config/edit/section/checkout/key/0ad75a974774456d274ebf7c4bcf4cb1/
>   [Tue Nov 29 20:25:40.318986 2016] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 306946:tid 140107373123328] (22)Invalid argument: [client 222.153.188.223:55836] AH01075: Error dispatching request to :, referer: http://baoho.nz/index.php/admin/system_config/edit/section/checkout/key/0ad75a974774456d274ebf7c4bcf4cb1/

I did change .htaccess file's memory limited from 64MB to 512MB. However, it still showed the same error. Could anyone help me to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Always try Googling the `ModSecurity: Output filter: Response body too large`  error message first (although it's admittedly hard to tell the message from the fluff in this case.) Possible duplicate of [Mod Security response/request body size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470051/mod-security-response-request-body-size)

Comment: Same problem are clear cache ?

Comment: Please add `.htaccess` code which is located at `/var/www/vhosts/baoho.nz/httpdocs/app/etc/` and also specify which permission and ownership of the `/var/www/vhosts/baoho.nz/httpdocs/app/etc/local.xml` file.