# SimpleHTMLDom returns 500 error on printing output

Tags: php, curl, fopen, file-get-contents, simple-html-dom

While trying to print the output of the simplehtmldom it gives me 500 error. I tried followed methods but error was same.

- **Method 1**

  $html = file_get_html("http://www.google.com");

  print_r($html);

  After reading responses to other questions, I checked if allow_url_fopen was working and it was.
- **Method 2**

  $html = file_get_contents("http://www.google.com");

  print_r($html);

  This works but when I parse it with following code, again 500 error.

  $object = new simple_html_dom();

  $object->load($html);

  var_dump($object);
- **Method 3**

  Then as last resort I thought I should try using curl and then parse. So I used curl and to make sure curl was working i printed the output at it was working. But when I parsed into the simplehtmldom again 500 error on printing the output.

> [Sat Sep 08 21:26:19.456961 2018] [:error] [pid 703804] ModSecurity:
>   Output filter: Response body too large (over limit of 404800001, total
>   not specified).

I increased the limit almost a 100 times but still the same error.

Comment: This looks like a recursion of some kind the document would be 404 MB big, that does not look like a HTML document...

Comment: try `$object->load($html); ob_start();var_dump($object);$len=strlen(ob_get_clean());var_dump($len);` ...

Comment: @hanshenrik unfortunately same 500 error

Comment: @arkascha well that beats me.. i mean i downloaded a new file of simplehtmldom too just incase I had messed up my original file for some reason but still same error.

Comment: @SaadBashir no i don't think that's the same error, what does the error log say this time?

Comment: Try to get it working from php command line first. That will eliminate errors your web server is creating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates ModSecurity is complaining about **Response body being too large**. This does not mean there is something wrong with loading HTML using Simple HTML DOM library, it is about the size of response generated by your code (`print_r` or `var_dump` parts). I guess this is because the structure of the HTML you're loading requires lots of nested objects to represent DOM tree, so when you try to output the full structure using `print_r` or `var_dump` the response becomes too large.

You can verify that the HTML is loaded and parsed by simply printing the plain HTML of the page (use `print` instead of `print_r` to print simple_html_dom object):

```
$html = file_get_html("http://www.google.com");

print($html);
```

and you will see the HTML is retrieved correctly, and you can work with `$html` object to manipulate DOM the way you expect to work with simple_html_dom objects.

If you want to change the output limit for ModSecurity so you can generate larger responses, please have a look at this question: [Mod Security response/request body size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470051/mod-security-response-request-body-size)

Comment: Thank you @Nima using print brings the output. Will now work on the second part of your answer about Mod Security and lets see how that goes! :D

Comment: tried increasing the body size by almost 100 times and yet no luck

Comment: As the answer on the other question says, the default response size is 512K so 100 times might be still less than enough, and it also says there is a hard limit of 1GB.

Comment: my previous limit was 3.86M which i increased to 386M. But same error persisted

Comment: To check if the cause of the problem is response limit, I suggest you go for the maximum possible limit, which is 1GB. If it worked, you can adjust it. But I'm curious, why do you need to `print_r` this object at all?